# Regular expression for quoted text and special characters

Tags: c#, .net, xml, regex

I'm trying to figure out a regular expression in .NET that can detect the XML special characters that are enclosed in quotation marks. They can contain other characters as well but at least one ocurrence of the following has to exist `< > & ' "`

Matches

```
"Hello &"
"& Something"
"Testing <>"
```

Does not match

```
"foo bar"
```

I've tried expressions like `"[&<>\"\'\w\s]+"` but this regex does accepts strings where the special characters are absent.

The purpose of this expression is to cleanse all XML Attributes from special characters that might crash parsers.

Comment: This is going to be very tricky if the quotes within the enclosed quotes are not escaped, as any REGEX pattern won't know which quote is the ending quite and which is merely a quote within the match. Also, your match is failing because your character class requires only that ONE of the enclosed characters is present, not all of them.

Comment: For " you may just need to look for more than two.  Do your strings begin and end with "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex says that any string of any of those characters (e.g. `\w`) should match.  Try this instead:

```
    ^.*[&<>\"\'].*$
```

You shouldn't need to escape those quotes, though.

And I hope you're using a DOM parser to retrieve the attribute values...

Comment: Also, if you need the ``<>`` to appear in sequence, you can try this: ``^.*([&"']|<.*>).*$``.

Comment: How does that deal with inside "?

Comment: @Blam, I took his question to mean removal of special characters from attribute values, and "that are enclosed in quotation marks" was just his way of describing that.  I suggested in my answer that he should be using a DOM parser to retrieve those attribute values.  If he is trying to do this purely in regex, then I have no answer for him.

Comment: I am not sure what he meant either.

Comment: What I have for the moment is a string that contains XML formatted data.. if I try to load that string into an XMLDocument object it will crash if it has any invalid characters in the attributes, that's why I'm stuck.